# Sending push notifications using post requests(manually)(Parse-server)?

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, parse-server

with Parse.com I used to be able to send push notifications via simple https post requests, something like:

`{
  "registration_ids": ["some_device_token_from_the_dashboard"],
  "data": { "title": "How are you", "message": "Ok?" }
}`

I added a `json` content type and set Authorization to `key=server_key`.

Another tool that could be used is: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/gcm.html

Anyway, I'm working with the **android SDK v4.13.1** and **Parse-server v2.2.16**, when I use the dashboard to send push notification to everyone I get the notification, but when I try the post request that used to work with parse.com, the response is:

`{
  "multicast_id": 8851650859439498656,
  "success": 1, "failure": 0,
  "canonical_ids": 0,
  "results":[ { "message_id":   "0:1470077514727128%33b2cdf9f9fd7ecd" } ]
}`

It looks like all is find but I don't get the notification at all, btw at the google console I didn't set the IP field so it accepts requests from 0.0.0.0(all interfaces), I assume there something I'm missing here, should the post request be different, what am I doing wrong?, is that a bug or?...

**Edit:**
Just to clerify, I implement my on `PushReceiver` that extends `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver`, and as before when I try to send push via simple post request(using my server-key and registration id) it won't work(the `onPushReceive` method never called).

**POST request details:**
My endpoint is `https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send`(I did try `gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send` as well)(https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http for more details), `Content-Type` set to `application/json` and `Authorization` set to `key=server_key`, the content is given at the beginning of the question.

Comment: you are using parse android SDK? can you please share the code where you are calling parse-server..

Comment: @RanHassid Thanks for the comment but I'm not using cloud code or client code to send pushes, I'm subscribing to a channel and then sending push from the dashboard that working, what I can't get to work is sending pushes with simple post request as in my question.

Comment: What is your http endpoint URL? do you execute POST request to the Parse push endpoint?

Comment: @RanHassid I will add those to my question...

Comment: This endpoint is not parse endpoint but google gcm endpoint so you want to call gcm directly or call parse that will call to gcm ?

Comment: @RanHassid I can use parse and it's working when I refer to gcm via parse, but when I refer to gcm directly it won't work although I've done it before so many time using with parse.com apps.

Comment: Can i ask why you want to call gcm directly ? it can be done by using parse or other push providers which also provide you the capability of sending notifications to multiple platforms (e.g. android,ios,windows etc.)

Comment: @RanHassid When I debug an app, instead of running the code(parse code) to call cloud code or directly from client code(if I allow) to send push notifications I used to directly call gcm(development done for android first), then I can play with the payload, change data rapidly via simple chrome extension(that sends requests)(can be done via `curl` as well).

Comment: Yes, but you can also call parse REST API via the curl in the same way. This way you have one endpoint for all your push scenarios .  so instead of calling the gcm API you call to parse REST api and it will do exactly the same behind the scenes. You can read more about it here: http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/rest/guide/#push-notification

Comment: @RanHassid You are right I never thought about the rest, thank you.